# Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i need to use a future builder to get the value of a radio button form shared preferences.
but the error occurs when i open the page of the radio button **is:**

```
Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
```

**the radio button widget is:**

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
                          future: getDayNotificationIsOn(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            return NeumorphicSwitch(
                              value: snapshot.data!,
                              style: NeumorphicSwitchStyle(
                                thumbShape: NeumorphicShape.flat,
                                activeTrackColor: const Color(0xff257864),
                              ),
                              onChanged: (value) async {
                                setState(() {});
                                //sharedPreferences
                                await setDayNotificationIsOn(value);
                              },
                            );
                          }),
```

**the function used in future builder to get the value of the radio button:**

```
  Future<bool> getDayNotificationIsOn() async {
    SharedPreferences _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return  _pref.getBool('dayNotificationIsOn') ?? false;
  }
```

Comment: You should add a check before `NeumorphicSwitch` to make sure the snapshot has data by adding `if (snapshot.hasData)`.

Comment: make your comment as a solution to approve it, thanks a lot @ZeeshanAhmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a check before `NeumorphicSwitch` to make sure the snapshot has data by adding `if (snapshot.hasData)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `snapshot.data` is null and `snapshot.data!` is firing this exception